# Unity Scene Change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a scene change when all enemies have been defeated, here is what i have so far

```
public class areOpponentsDead : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<GameObject> listOfOpponents = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        listOfOpponents.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"));
        print(listOfOpponents.Count);
    }

    public void KilledOpponent(GameObject enemy)
    {
        if(listOfOpponents.Contains(opponent))
        {
            listOfOpponents.Remove(opponent);
        }

        print(listOfOpponents.Count);
    }

    public bool AreOpponentsDead()
    {
        if(listOfOpponents.Count <= 0)
        {
            Application.LoadScene("Level2");
        }
    }
}
```

i dont know if i should link this to an existing script or make a new one and how to connect this to the game.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Answer (score 0):

I put this feature in 1 of my games and my enemy script performed a check every time an enemy died.
The function looked like:

```
void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        if (gameManager != null)
        {
            if (gameManager.GetEnemies - 1 == 0)
            {
                gameManager.Invoke("WinLevel", 1f);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is common practice to use a Game Manager for managing your game so here, my `gameManager` script tracks the number of enemies in my game in the function `GetEnemies`. It also only makes sense that it is responsible for changing scenes (In the function `WinLevel` in my case).
And this script is attached to a Game Manager object.

You can then either:

1. Make a reference to the Game Manager in the enemy script or...
2. Make a static instance of the script

Edit: The GameManager script has the following code:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The integer is the index for the current scene and the string is the name of the scene
    public string nextLevel = "2";
    public int levelToUnlock = 2;

    public GameObject winMenu;
    public GameObject gameplayUI;
    public GameObject backgroundMusic;
    GameObject player;
    Rigidbody2D playerRigidbody2D;
    public AudioClip winMusic;
    public int GetEnemies { get { return GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length; } }
    private void Start()
    {
        GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript._Adins.DestroyBanner();
    }
    public void WinLevel()
    {
        GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript._Adins.ShowBannerAd();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        playerRigidbody2D = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerRigidbody2D.simulated = false;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelReached", levelToUnlock);
        winMenu.SetActive(true);
        gameplayUI.SetActive(false);
        backgroundMusic.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        backgroundMusic.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(winMusic);
    }
    public void NextLevel()
    {
        GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript._Adins.DestroyBanner();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevel);
    }
    public void RestartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```